# How to properly deallocate memory?

Tags: c++, memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

Classes:

```
class Menuitem
{
private:
    char* text;

    Menuitem();
    Menuitem(const char*);
    ~Menuitem();
    Menuitem(const Menuitem& ) = delete;
    Menuitem& operator=(const Menuitem& ) = delete;
    friend class Menu;
public:
};

class Menu
{
private:
    char* title;
    Menuitem* items;
    int identation = 0;
    int amount = 0;
public:
    Menu();
    Menu(const char*, int = 0);
    ~Menu();
    bool isEmpty() const;
    int run() const;
    void add(const char*);
    void display() const;
    Menu& operator=(const char* nTitle);
    operator int() const;
    Menu& operator=(const Menu& );
    operator bool() const;
    Menu& operator<<(const char* );
};
```

Functions:

```
Menu& Menu::operator=(const char* nTitle)
{
    if (nTitle[0] != '\0' && title[0] != '\0')
    {
        delete[] title;
        title = new char[strlen(nTitle)+1];
        strcpy(title, nTitle);
    }
    else if (title[0] != '\0' && nTitle == 0)
    {
        delete[] title;
        title = nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        title = nullptr;
    }
    return *this;
}

Menu& Menu::operator=(const Menu& nMenu)
{
    if (nMenu.title[0] != '\0' && title[0] != '\0')
    {
        delete[] title;
        title = new char[strlen(nMenu.title)+1];
        strcpy(title, nMenu.title);
    }
    else if (nMenu.title[0] == '\0' && title[0] != '\0')
    {
        delete[] title;
        title = nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        title = nullptr;
    }


    if (!amount)
        for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
        {
            if (items[i].text[0] != '\0')
            {
                delete[] items[i].text;
                items[i].text = nullptr;
            }
        }
    amount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < nMenu.amount; i++)
    {
        if (nMenu.items[i].text != nullptr)
        {
            items[i].text = new char[strlen(nMenu.items[i].text)+1];
            strcpy(items[i].text, nMenu.items[i].text);
        }
        else
        {
            items[i].text = nullptr;
        }
    }
    amount = nMenu.amount;
    identation = nMenu.identation;
    return *this;
}
```

My code has a lot of functions but I think that these (or maybe one of these) functions cause an error. The code displays what I need, but in the end when I clean the pointers from Menu using destructor

> Menu::~Menu(){delete[] title; delete[] items;}

I receive these errors:

> malloc: Incorrect checksum for freed object 0x102832838: probably modified after being freed.

Maybe I'm trying to double delete something, but I cant't find what and where

Comment: use `std::string` instead of char pointers and manual memory management; all these problems will go away

Comment: I'm not allowed to use `std::string`

Comment: In that case make your own class which is just like std::string (you have to do that same work anyway and it is much easier to have it in its own class where you can test it, than to have it mixed up with the Menu class code)

Comment: Assuming you're on a Linux box, have you tried using `valgrind` or compiling your code with address sanitization?

Answer (score 2):

> How to properly deallocate memory?

By managing the allocation with a RAII container such as `std::string`.

---

If you're required to do manual memory management, then follow these rules:

- Never manage memory in any class other than one whose only responsibility is to manage that memory.
- Always have exactly one delete for each new. Never delete anything more than once.
- Only use `delete` for `new` and `delete[]` for `new[]`.
- Never delete anything that wasn't returned by new.
- Always initialise the owning pointer in every constructor.
- Never let the owning pointer to point to anything other than a valid object or nullptr as a class invariant.
- Never let an owning pointer have the same value as another object as a class invariant.
- Never assign to the owning pointer unless you have just deleted it.
- Never delete the owning pointer unless you immediately assign a valid value to it (except in destructor, where you only need to delete).
- Never delete the pointer in anywhere except in the class where you allocated it.
- Implement all five of destructor,copy/move constructor/assignment.

---

> Maybe I'm trying to double delete something, but I cant't find what and where

Start by creating a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I'm not allowed to use `std::string`

Comment: @Dr_Cringe Then use `std::unique_ptr<char[]>` instead.

Comment: I can't use this as well. I have to do it using char pointers

Comment: @Dr_Cringe Then use char pointer to implement your own string class so that you don't need to repeat the memory management code for every class that needs it.